# MongoDB: When do secondaries know write is majority-confirmed?

Tags: mongodb

When writes are using w:majority Primary will wait until required (majority) number of secondaries confirm the operation before acknowledging the write.

When reads are targeting secondaries, and read concern of "majority" is used, Mongo will return majority-confirmed reads.  It doesn't guarantee it will be the latest write, just the fact that it was confirmed a majority members of the replica set and is therefore "durable".

My questions:

1. How and when do secondaries find it write was majority-acknowledged?
   I understand secondaries poll for changes to oplog, returning confirmations to a primary.  In order for secondaries to be able to handle reads with read concern of majority, they need to know which of the writes where majority-confirmed.  How do they find out?  Do they find out before w:majority acknowledges the operation, or after?  In other words, is read (read concern majority) to a node known to have acknowledged the write following the w:majority write a linearizable operation?
2. Is it safe to assume that all acknowledged writes with {w:majority, j:true} are durable and will sustain failure of a primary, and all non-acknowledged writes may (but not will) get rolled back?
   If, in a 4-node cluster, if {w:majority, j:true} write is confirmed and acknowledged by N1 (Primary), N2, and N3, but not yet N4, upon failure of a Primary N1 the will the write be available regardless which node is selected a new primary, including if it was node N4?
   Conversely, if {w:majority, j:true} write has not been confirmed, and acknowledged only by N1 (Primary) and N2, upon failure of a Primary N1 will the write ever be available regardless which node is selected a new primary, including the scenario when N3 has applied the write by confirmation has never reached failing N1 Primary node?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How and when do secondaries find it write was majority-acknowledged?
>    I understand secondaries poll for changes to oplog, returning confirmations to a primary. In order for secondaries to be able to handle reads with read concern of majority, they need to know which of the writes where majority-confirmed. How do they find out? Do they find out before w:majority acknowledges the operation, or after? In other words, is read (read concern majority) to a node known to have acknowledged the write following the w:majority write a linearizable operation?

Each node has its own commit point (similar to a pointer to an oplog entry which replicated to majority nodes), and this commit point is used for building "committed snapshot", which is employed for read operations with a majority concern.

The primary node updates its commit point when it receives "replSetUpdatePosition" commands from secondary nodes. The "replSetUpdatePosition" command contains the "last applied OpTime" and "last durable OpTime." The primary node uses these values for commit point calculation.

A secondary node updates its commit point when it sends the "replSetHeartbeat" command. The response to this command will contain "ReplSetMetadata" that includes the "last committed OpTime", and the secondary node uses this value to calculate its commit point.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/repl/README.md

- about "replSetUpdatePosition" command:

  > If the receiving node is a primary and it learns that the commit point should be moved forward, it does so.
- about "replSetHeartbeat" command:

  > Secondaries advance their commit point via heartbeats by checking if the commit point is in the same term as their lastApplied OpTime.

Answer (score -1):

> How and when do secondaries find it write was majority-acknowledged?

Secondaries don't need to know that. The writes are always sent from the application to the primary, hence the *primary* needs to know when the write is majority-acknowledged, but none of the secondaries do.

The primary, in my understanding, knows the oplog pointer of all of the secondaries (or at least the ones it's waiting for). When this pointer advances past the write being waited for, the primary can return success to the application issuing the majority write.

> Is it safe to assume that all acknowledged writes with {w:majority, j:true} are durable and will sustain failure of a primary, and all non-acknowledged writes may (but not will) get rolled back?

That is my understanding.

> Conversely, if {w:majority, j:true} write has not been confirmed, and acknowledged only by N1 (Primary) and N2, upon failure of a Primary N1 will the write ever be available regardless which node is selected a new primary, including the scenario when N3 has applied the write by confirmation has never reached failing N1 Primary node?

If N3 has applied the write, I believe the write may survive, but I am not an expert in the finer details of the server's behavior such as this one.

It also seems to me that the write may survive even if it didn't make it to N3 (and hence it only exists on one of the 3 available nodes). Interesting question to test.

Comment: Secondaries do need to know a write was majority-acknowledged in order to satisfy a query with the read concern majority.  This is documented here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern-majority.  It's not clear exactly how secondaries receive the majority-acknowledged notices, and if it's done before or after w:majoirty write operation returns. Example in documentation is for w:1 write and seem to suggest majority-acknowledgement propagation happens after write operation concludes.  This would suggest non-leniarizable nature of write-followed-by-a-read with majority concerns.

Comment: For linearizability, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern-linearizable/. Majority read concern is insufficient.